# PhpStorm - Disable SQL inspection for one line

Tags: phpstorm, code-inspection

I am using the `ZendDb` database adapter which doesn't bring all the tweaks `SQL` can do. For example if I want to do a `REPLACE INTO` I would have to code it like this:

```
$SQL = sprintf('REPLACE INTO %s (id, NAME, cache_id, compile_id, content) VALUES  (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' %
        array(self::TABLE_NAME, $id, $name, $cache_id, $compile_id));
$this->_zdb->query($SQL);
```

The problem is that PhpStorm tells me that the `%s` is an error inside the SQL.

When I try hotfixing it with <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> I don't get the option to suppress the inspection for this line.

I' need something like this:

```
/** @noinspection SqlInspection */
```

I googled and found [this](https://gist.github.com/discordier/ed4b9cba14652e7212f5) page but nothing of the options seemed to help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well -- your code seems to be fine here, excluding the unknown column names of course, as I do not have the Database definition (I've selected MySQL dialect in PhpStorm). This must be because I have a rule for `%s` placeholders/parameters -- quite possibly I have added it manually long time ago and it's not provided by default in your version (what PhpStorm version do you use anyway)? So ... check your patterns at `Settings/Preferences | Tools | Database | User Parameters` -- see if you have `\%\w+` pattern there; if you do -- what's the definition?

Comment: It may solve it for you so no suppression may be required. I cannot post this as an answer straight away because you may have some another code sample where this will not be enough and actual suppression will be required.

Comment: He complains `<reference> expected, got %`. But I think just the correct ignore param would be ok as well :)

Comment: That's what User Parameters are for -- for dynamic assembling the final SQL, be it ordinary placeholders (prepared statements) or alike .. or assembling actual SQL with `sprintf`. So .. does adding such aforementioned `\%\w+` pattern helps or not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `\%\w+` pattern to `Settings/Preferences | Tools | Database | User Parameters` -- it will tell IDE to treat such `%s` as dynamic/external part of the code instead of actual SQL.

For example:

[image]

**P.S.**
One day such pattern will be provided by default in PhpStorm.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-39271 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

If you need an actual suppression .. then the most effective way is to treat the string as Plain Text instead of autodetected SQL.

For this, just place `/** @lang text*/` just before the string, e.g.

```
$sql = /** @lang text*/'REPLACE INTO %s (id, NAME, cache_id, compile_id, content) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)';
```

[image]

NOTE: may not work if you are concatenating such string or perform other manipulations in place.